# Where are the user information stored in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a tricky problem with SSRS. One of my users had his AD account renamed, so the SID stayed the same. When ever the user tries to create a new report or modify an existing his display name under "created by" or "modified by" still shows the old account name. I went into the SSRS DB and looked into the dbo.user table, there the name is correct. But there must be another location where SSRS keeps this information. How can I fix this ? Restarting SSRS didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the problem, as indicated the dbo.user table is not the problem. However on the SQL Server Instance there was still a login with the old AD account name. Seems SQL Server is not able to deal with a rename of an AD account. After removing the login and the db user and recreating this with the newly named AD account suddenly all the owner information on the SSRS objects have been correct.